# How can I understand the rate limit of storefront api (Shopify Api)

Tags: node.js, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

Shopify has removed the rate limit on storefront api so but how can I understand it I mean if I use the storefront nodejs api they communicate with the admin api:

https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-js

> This library provides support for the backends of TypeScript/JavaScript Shopify apps to access the Shopify Admin API, by making it easier to perform the following actions:

So but at the admin api they are rate limits. So if I make request with the storefront libary to admin api do I have any rate limits ?